# O que significa o "MZ" listado no início de código executável?

Tags: windows, .exe, ms-dos

Nos bons tempos do MS-DOS eu executava o comando `type <nome-do-arquivo>` em arquivos `.EXE` e aparecia um monte de caracteres ASCII (indicativo de código binário) iniciados pela sigla `MZ`.

Sempre quis saber o que é esse `MZ`, mas nunca tive a curiosidade de ir atrás. Quem sabe o SOpt mata essa minha curiosidade.

Para deixar a resposta completa, gostaria que fossem explicados o que fazem as instruções iniciais do arquivo `.EXE`. O `MZ` tem algum uso? Os caracteres seguintes são responsáveis por que tipo de inicialização (leia-se: existe um cabeçalho)? Ou não ocorre nenhuma inicialização, apenas o programa é movido para a memória e posto para executar a partir da sua primeira instrução?

Comment: Meio extenso responder isso tudo, você teria que estudar o formato PE da Microsoft. Sobre o MZ, são as iniciais do Mark Zbikowski, um desenvolvedor do MS-DOS, e ele só está nos EXE como indicador de compatibilidade de subsistemas 16 bits (se tentar rodar um executável moderno no MS-DOS vai receber a mensagem de que a aplicação não pode ser executada em DOS, e esse aviso é a unica "funcionalidade" da "parte DOS" do executável) - O MZ diferencia o .exe do .com em sistemas 16 bits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É uma assinatura de executável. É uma forma simples e ingênua de verificar se o executável está em determinado formato. Se tudo estiver certo funciona, mas pode ser algo forjado ou coincidente, é improvável, mas pode acontecer, e claro que tem outras validações, mas esta é a primeira que é feita, se não encontrar isso já sabe que esse formato não é.

Segundo a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_MZ_executable) é abreviação do Mark Zbikowski, o cara que criou participou da criação.

Os bytes que veem a seguir são mais significativos e começam informar a composição deste executável específico. Neste tipo de formato há um tratamento bem complexo para inicializar e preparar a memória, apenas um formato bem antigo que consegue ir direto para a memória sem tratamento específico.

O caso de ser um MZ, ou seja, um executável DOS das antigas tem pouca informação específica seguinte, outros formatos (PE) são bem mais ricos.

Os executáveis mais novos ainda contém o "MZ" por questões de compatibilidade então não dá um erro qualquer se chamar um executável moderno em um sistema antigo, dará um erro mais específico que o próprio executável fornece. Isto é interessante porque sistemas mais antigos não entendem formatos novos e dariam um erro genérico.

- Uma [listagem](https://www.fileformat.info/format/exe/corion-mz.htm) de como ele pode ser composto.
- O [OSDev](https://wiki.osdev.org/MZ) tem uma forma bem simplificada.
- E tem um [Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Windows_Executable_Files) com um resumo um pouco maior de como é o formato do PE moderno que acho mais interessante.
- [Documentação da Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- E um [código](https://www.bigmessowires.com/2015/10/08/a-handmade-executable-file/) se quiser escrever um executável na mão.

De qualquer forma parece bastante amplo tentar descrever tudo aqui.

Veja o [diagrama da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable):

[image: Diagrama do formato do PE]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).