# Qual é a diferença entre binário e executável?

Tags: terminologia, .exe, arquitetura-computadores, linguagem-de-máquina

Um arquivo binário e um executável quer dizer a mesma coisa para a programação?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um binário é um arquivo que é codificado com bytes diversos (de 0 a 255) que pode ou não ter um formato definido. E o conteúdo pode ser variado também, o que tem ali define a semântica daquilo. O binário pode ser o termo oposto do arquivo ser de texto (que tecnicamente não deixa de ser um binário), restrito a alguns bytes que podem ser lidos por humanos e que costumam ter quebras de linhas.

Provavelmente quando está comparando com um executável estamos falando de um código que foi gerado de forma binária, provavelmente por um compilador, ou um montador, e tem condições de ser executado, provavelmente de forma direta pelo processador. Mas existem códigos que podem ser considerados binários e precisam ainda de alguma manipulação para ser executado. Para ser executado de forma direta precisa ser um código nativo para aquela arquitetura de computador que está rodando.

Note que basta ter um código binário nativo para poder executar nativamente, e não precisaria nem estar em um arquivo.

Se o código binário não é nativo então precisará de alguma ferramenta para transformá-lo em uma forma de execução nativa ou precisará de uma interpretação. Sim, é possível interpretar um código binário, ainda que isso faça pouco sentido e não costume acontecer.

Para o código binário nativo executar precisará de alguma ajuda de hardware, firmware ou até de software. O sistema operacional pode ser essa ajuda, mas não costuma ter um software nele para executar o binário nativo diretamente, precisaria arrumar algo extra ou escrever algo que execute esse binário.

Não importa onde está o binário. Em algum momento ele deverá ir para a memória e depois para o processador.

Para facilitar o trabalho, o sistema operacional estabelece um formato onde coloca os binários e outras informações para facilitar essa execução. Esse formato é colocado em um arquivo chamado executável. Desta forma se invocar esse arquivo em formato válido para o SO ele sabe o que fazer, como colocar na memória, como deve tratar esse binário e permite a execução facilmente dentro de tudo o que ele espera.

Em geral não é possível executar diretamente um arquivo nesse formato que chamamos de executável porque o processador não sabe como lidar com ele.

Tecnicamente um binário nativo é um código executável, mas sem um formato que usamos para dizer que é executável, talvez um `.exe`.

Mais ainda, algumas pessoas chamam o código fonte de algumas linguagens que interpretam ou compilam na hora esse código de código executável também, mas provavelmente não é o mesmo que estamos falando aqui.

Além de códigos nativos ou não nativos, os executáveis podem incluir textos (pode ser até código fonte não diretamente executável) ou outros tipos de dados binários, incluindo imagens e dados compactados. Em resumo o executável é um *container* para dados binários ou não, executáveis ou não, ainda que a preferência seja para os binários executáveis.

Veja mais:

- [O que significa o "MZ" listado no início de código executável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/403699/101)
- [Os novos executáveis auto-contidos do .NET são realmente nativos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/413345/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).